# Using PHP & curl to post an html form that includes a file

Tags: php, post, curl

I have a form like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="i.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="text" name="field1">
 <input type="text" name="field2">
 <input type="file" name="file">
 <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000">
 <input type="submit">
</form>
```

On the page I already have:

```
$URL = 'http://somewhere.com/catch.php';
$fields = array('field1'=>urlencode($_POST['field1'), 'field2'=>urlencode($_POST['field2'));

    foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string  .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; };

    rtrim($fields_string,'&');
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
```

That works to post the field1 & 2 fields.
Is it possible to include the file in that curl process somehow?  How would I do that?  I'm assuming I have to do more than just encode the file value.

So based on SimpleCoders' answer I updated to the following:

```
$URL = 'http://somewhere.com/catch.php';
$fields = array('field1'=>urlencode($_POST['field1'), 'field2'=>urlencode($_POST['field2'), 'files'=>'@'. $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

    foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string  .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; };

    rtrim($fields_string,'&');
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
```

which posts OK but then my resulting $_FILES array on catch.php is empty.  Accoring to Example #2 on http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php This should work.

I am doing this on two different domains...might that be a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this, taken [from here](http://forums.devshed.com/php-development/533233-php-curl-send-file-post2050179.html#post2050179):

```
$file_to_upload = array('file_contents'=>'@'.$file_name_with_full_path); 
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $file_to_upload); 
$result=curl_exec ($ch); 
curl_close ($ch); 
echo $result;
```

Also consider https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php, which appears to be an easier, more modern way of doing it.

Comment: Since there's no guarantee on the life of an external link, can you post the information here, and leave the reference?

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow SimpleCoders answer but then change your

```
$fields_string
```

to just

```
$fields.
```

From http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Note: Passing an array to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS will encode the data as multipart/form-data, while passing a URL-encoded string will encode the data as application/x-www-form-urlencoded.